# "Change" as much whitespace as necessary

Tags: formatting

I'm editing a table in extended-markdown, and I'm wondering how to easily edit cells without moving the dividing lines.

Tables are formatted like this:

```
| HEADING1         | HEADING2       | etc...
| ---------------- | -------------- | etc...
| row 1            | column2        | etc...
| etc...
```

Suppose I want to change an entry but leave the next `|` in its place. Ideally, I'd go to the first word in the cell and use `c<something>`, type the new entry, and, upon leaving `insert` mode, a sufficient number of spaces would be inserted or deleted after the new text to ensure that the `|` character is restored to its original location, *if possible*. (Obviously if too much text is entered, this won't be possible; one solution for this would be to somehow restrict the insert operation to the maximum number of characters to permit retaining the cell-shape, though I don't know if Vim permits this.)

This seems like it should be possible to implement by creating a new text-object or something, though I realize there would be a fair amount of "magic" involved since leaving insert mode would trigger a second edit operation.

Comment: [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) is a pretty nice plugin made especially for this.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How can I easily create and maintain tables?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/363/51).

Comment: @hgiesel Looks intriguing! Though possibly a bit too "smart."

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Nice self-promotion :) Yours is a much more general question but nevertheless quite helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the `R` operator? This will let you overwrite whatever text you need to without moving the `|`. If your word is shorter than what you're replacing, you can simply fill the rest with spaces.

See `:h R` for more info.

Comment: It's so simple. This is exactly what I was looking for; thanks.